# Which permutation of dominoes knocks over the end path?

Tags: visual, find-the-order

I made a short and simple domino puzzle, where there are four domino tracks that can be knocked over in any permutation, and the goal is to knock over the final path that will take down the domino fortress. Only one permutation should be able to do so.
[image: Domino Puzzle Picture]
Please note that when a domino hits two dominos that are perpendicular, then it is blocked, but a domino can knock over another domino over the top of the fallen dominoes, unless they are too far apart. This puzzle should be a simple, easy puzzle to solve. Here is a Powerpoint Shapes version: [image: Powerpoint slide screen grab]

Comment: May I suggest the tag [tag:mechanical-puzzle]? Also, do you think that a [tag:find-the-order] tag will be useful in general?

Comment: Have you read the wiki of [tag:mechanical-puzzle]. Does this really fit that definition? I do believe that [tag:find-the-order] has a use in categorising different puzzles with a similar theme.

Comment: It appears to me that you can knock over the paths in any order, and you will trigger the top path when you have knocked over the left-most path at the bottom. The top path leads to a grainy box at the top of the picture. It could be a humane mousetrap or a small Wi-Fi router, for all I can tell from the photo, but I guess that it is the domino fortress, since nothing else in the picture looks the least bit like a fortress. I can’t tell which way the dominoes in the fortress (if that’s what they are) are facing, so I don’t know whether being hit by a domino or two will take it down. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  I doubt that this is what you are thinking, so I’m not posting it as an answer.  I doubt that taking the same photograph again will help; you might get a better result if you use a better camera (or a better photographer).  A drawing of the layout (done with a drawing tool, like Paint or PowerPoint) might help.

Comment: @PeregrineRook I have a much better camera, this image is old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Number the four starting dominoes at the bottom from left to right 1 to 4.
>  
> I think the solution is 2 4 1.
>
> The last move is #1, as this is the only one that could activate the path to the fortress. However, the double-domino blockage needs to be removed first.
>  
> The path that removes the blockage leads back to only #4. However, tipping #4 first activates two paths that knock each other out, so the left of those two paths needs to be disabled first.
>  
> The path that causes that left one to be disabled leads back to #2 and #3. Tipping over #3 also tips over #2 (in reverse) and vice versa, but only #2 will disable the left path from #4.
>  This gives #2 before #4 before #1, and don't touch #3.